# How can I connect pellet with C#? (Loading ontology in C#.)

Tags: c#, pellet

I am running a [Pellet](http://clarkparsia.com/pellet/) 1.5.x server right now. I need to load an ontology in C# and do queries to the running server of Pellet. How do I do this?

I also need to know how the queries are managed by Pellet (what are the structure of the queries), well ty /wave.

Answer (score 0):

Is it running any web services or provide REST API's

If not, then you need to write one.

Other option is to see if it can be converted using iKvm